# Discord | Spacing In Embeds

Tags: python, discord, embed, discord.py, spacing

I'm a very experienced bot developer in python and I understand discord.py just to clarify that.

I'm wondering if anybody has the knowledge of any way to use tabs/multiple spaces in an embed. I have a hangman board that looks like this

```
--------
|     |
|     O
|    \|/
|     |
|    / \
-
```

In discord, the embed always gets rid of the spaces and the result ends up unaligned and skinny. I am unable to use the three gravestones because I require formatting such as bold that I can do with field names.

Does anybody have any clue of any way to do this with discord.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a decision that instead of using formatting as my background under text to just use emojis as my background and text. I just turned my hangman board into this.

```
⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬜⬛
⬜⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛
⬜⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛
⬜⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛
⬜⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛
⬜⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛
```

I used [this great website](https://emojipedia.org/discord/) to get my emojis in case anybody is interested.